What is the time sequence when a participle phrase is at the beginning versus the end of a sentence?
There are two sentences like below

Crying hard, he hugged his mother for the first time
He hugged his mother for the first time, crying hard.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences? What action is first and what action is later?
I want to know the time sequence in this sentences.

There is no "time sequence" in such sentences.  The two actions occur simultaneously or they intersect when one action is continuous and the other happens all at once:

Humming a tune, he looked at the cameras displayed in the shop window.
He looked at the cameras displayed in the shop window, humming a tune.
Boarding the bus, he tripped.
He tripped boarding the bus.


Maybe add the information from your other answer to make this more comprehensive?

Since that other answer doesn't address  time-sequence, I think it would be better to keep this answer as is for the sake of simplicity.

Very often in English, we use verbs to make verbal phrases, which can function as adjectives.
So here: Crying hard, he hugged his mother for the first time. avoids doing this: He was crying hard when he hugged his mother for the first time. But it has the same meaning as that.
The ing plus verb all describe him.
Another example: Laughing loudly, she ran out the door.
She ran out the door, laughing loudly.
That describes her.
These phrases can come at different places in a sentences.
The man, screaming very loud, ran out the door.
He hugged his mother for the first time, crying hard.
The phrase means that the verb in question is happening at the same moment as the action in the matrix (main) clause. The actions are simultaneous.
[Please use want to in writing here, not wanna.]

Not my downvote. I think someone must have objected to your saying the participial clause functions as an adjective.

@TimR Yes, that's probably right. When a very similar question was asked on ELU, I had said it was adverbial and was shot down.  I should post that here. The others kept saying it was adjectival. These phrases can be either one, depending but I ain't fighting about it. Too boring. Thanks for mentioning this.
